# Stack Exchange Web Banners

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, site-promotion

Are there any web banners I can use to promote Stack Overflow, Server Fault, etc.?

I don't want to use a flair banner.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, we don't have any banners per se, but I am OK with using the logos -- as long as they are linked back to the site.

We also now have an official logos page:

https://stackexchange.com/about/logos